# Change the url in browser bar without reloading page

Tags: javascript, url

I want to change the url in browser bar without reloading page.

```
<html><head>
 <title>Change url in browser bar</title>
</head>
     <body>
             <h1>Refresh page to see our other website</h1>
     </body>
 </html>
```

When any user enter my website like **www.a-site.com** After open this site he see the text  *Refresh page to see our other website*. Can I do that when he enter in **www.a-site.com**,   after this url change in browser bar like **www.b-site.com** and when user refresh page it   can automaticaaly redirect in
 **www.b-site.com**. can this is possible.
  Thanks...............

Comment: Use iframes to do that

Comment: Are they truly 2 different sites or different pages within same domain?

Comment: This is two different site.

Answer (score 11):

**You are looking for following**

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

Here is the original article I read (posted July 10, 2012): HTML5: [Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page.](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

**Example:**

```
 function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```

[Documentation](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/)

Comment: Doesn't work cross domain.